# testing username and password for iphone app review

Tags: iphone

My app has this one screen requires login, should I make a comment for the reviewer and provide a testing account?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, make a test account. They'll need access to all the functionality.

Comment: I wonder if the app uses only Facebook login, do you need to create a test Facebook account or assume they have one?

Comment: I would cover all your bases and create a test one (via https://developers.facebook.com/docs/test_users/). Five minutes worth of work could save you a week in re-review. Give Apple's reviewers **everything** they might possibly need that isn't their own fingers.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not provide a test account, they will kick the review back to you and request credentials, so it's not just a suggestion, it's a requirement.